# applying lambda row on multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

I am creating a sample dataframe:

```
tp = pd.DataFrame({'source':['a','s','f'], 
                   'target':['b','n','m'], 
                   'count':[0,8,4]})
```

And creating a column 'col' based on condition of 'target' column >> same as source, if matching condition, else to a default, as below:

```
tp['col'] = tp.apply(lambda row:row['source'] if row['target'] in ['b','n'] else 'x')
```

But it's throwing me this error: `KeyError: ('target', 'occurred at index count')`

How can I make it work, without defining a function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `axis=1` to tell Pandas you want to apply a function to each row. The default is `axis=0`.

```
tp['col'] = tp.apply(lambda row: row['source'] if row['target'] in ['b', 'n'] else 'x',
                     axis=1)
```

---

However, for this specific task, you should use vectorised operations. For example, using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
tp['col'] = np.where(tp['target'].isin(['b', 'n']), tp['source'], 'x')
```

[`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) returns a Boolean series which tells `numpy.where` whether to select the second or third argument.