# Ignoring an invalid filter among multiple filters on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### Problem Statement:

I have a DataFrame that has to be filtered with multiple conditions.

Each condition is optional, which means if an invalid value is entered by the user for a certain condition, the condition can be skipped completely, defaulting to the original DataFrame (without that specific condition)in return.

While I can implement this quite easily with multiple if-conditions, modifying the DataFrame in a sequential way, I am looking for something that is more elegant and scalable (with increasing input parameters) and preferably using inbuilt pandas functionality

#### Reproducible Example

Dummy dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'One':['a','a','a','b'], 
                   'Two':['x','y','y','y'], 
                   'Three':['l','m','m','l']})

print(df)
```

```
  One Two Three
0   a   x     l
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
3   b   y     l
```

Let's say that invalid values are the values that don't belong to the respective column. So, for column 'One' all other values are invalid except 'a' and 'b'. If the user input's 'a' then I should be able to filter the DataFrame `df[df['One']=='a']`, however, if the user inputs any invalid value, no such filter should be applied, and the original dataframe `df` is returned.

My attempt (with multiple parameters):

```
def valid_filtering(df, inp):
    if inp[0] in df['One'].values:
        df = df[df['One']==inp[0]]

    if inp[1] in df['Two'].values:
        df = df[df['Two']==inp[1]]

    if inp[2] in df['Three'].values:
        df = df[df['Three']==inp[2]]
        
    return df
```

With all valid inputs -

```
inp = ['a','y','m']             #<- all filters valid so df is filtered before returning
print(valid_filtering(df, inp))
```

```
  One Two Three
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
```

With few invalid inputs -

```
inp = ['a','NA','NA']           #<- only first filter is valid, so other 2 filters are ignored
print(valid_filtering(df, inp))
```

```
  One Two Three
0   a   x     l
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
```

---

**P.S.** Additional question - is there a way to get DataFrame indexing to behave as -

```
df[df['One']=='valid'] -> returns filtered df

df[df['One']=='invalid'] -> returns original df
```

Because this would help me rewrite my filtering -

```
df[(df['One']=='valid') & (df['Two']=='invalid') & (df['Three']=='valid')] -> Filtered by col One and Three
```

Comment: In your second case are `'valid'` and `'invalid'` actually those strings, or just a valid or invalid value? But seems like your problem can be mostly solved by having a dict as an argument, something like `d = {'One': 'a'}` or `d = {'One': 'a', 'Two': 'y', 'Three': 'm'}`, that way you can more flexibly specify some or all of the columns you'd need to filter, iterating over the dict, instead of having basically the same logic copied 3x

Comment: Thats just an example, valid and invalid values is what I am referring to.

Comment: The dictionary-based filter is definitely something that I can use, using `df.loc[df[filter_v.keys()].isin(filter_v.values()).all(axis=1), :]` but, the issue is then that I have to collect the list of valid and invalid values before I can create the filter dictionary. [link for reference](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/58593/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-using-values-from-a-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way creating a Boolean dataframe depending on each value of inp in each column. Then use `any` along the rows to get columns with at least one True, and `all` along the columns once selected the columns that have at least one True.

```
def valid_filtering(df, inp):
    # check where inp values are same than in df
    m = (df==pd.DataFrame(data=[inp] , index=df.index, columns=df.columns))
    # select the columns with at least one True
    cols = m.columns[m.any()]
    # select the rows that all True amongst wanted columns
    rows = m[cols].all(axis=1)
    # return df with selected rows
    return df.loc[rows]
```

Note that if you don't have the same number of filter than columns in your original df, then you could do with a dictionary, it works too as in the example below the column Three will be ignored as all `False`.

```
d = {'One': 'a', 'Two': 'y'}
m = (df==pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index).reindex(columns=df.columns))
```

Comment: Great thanks, I combined your solution with Corralien's solution to come up with a code that I finally used. Updated my answer, Thanks!

Comment: @AkshaySehgal awesome solution you got, I'm a bit surprised that doing a or operation between the full dataframe df.eq(inp) and the series ~df.eq(inp).any(0) works this way but  I'll try to remember this for later :)

Answer (score 1):

The key is if a column return all False (`~b.any`, invalid filter) then return True to accept all values of this columns:

```py
mask = df.eq(inp).apply(lambda b: np.where(~b.any(), True, b))
out = df.loc[mask.all(axis="columns")]
```

**Case 1**: `inp = ['a','y','m']` (with all valid inputs)

```py
>>> out
  One Two Three
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
```

**Case 2**: `inp = ['a','NA','NA']` (with few invalid inputs)

```py
>>> out
  One Two Three
0   a   x     l
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
```

**Case 3**: `inp = ['NA','NA','NA']` (with no invalid inputs)

```py
>>> out
  One Two Three
0   a   x     l
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
3   b   y     l
```

**Case 4**: `inp = ['b','x','m']` (with all valid inputs but not results)

```
>>> out
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [One, Two, Three]
Index: []
```

Of course, you can increase input parameters:

```py
df["Four"] = ['i','j','k','k']
inp = ['a','NA','m','k']
```

```
>>> out
  One Two Three Four
2   a   y     m    k
```

Comment: Great solution, I took inspiration from your solution and the solution by Ben.T to come up with a logic without use of an apply method. Details in my updated answer.

Comment: too bad I can only mark a single answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Another way with list comprehension:

```
def valid_filtering(df, inp):
    series = [df[column] == inp[i]
        for i, column in enumerate(df.columns) if len(df[df[column] == inp[i]].values) > 0]
    for s in series: df = df[s]
    return df
```

Output of `print(valid_filtering(df, ['a','NA','NA']))`:

```
  One Two Three
0   a   x     l
1   a   y     m
2   a   y     m
```

Related: [applying lambda row on multiple columns pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080174/applying-lambda-row-on-multiple-columns-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

An updated solution inspired by the code and logic provided by [Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477486/5446749) and [Ben.T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477458/5446749):

```py
df.loc[(df.eq(inp)|~df.eq(inp).any(0)).all(1)]
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67476889/3) to the question [Ignoring an invalid filter among multiple filters on a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67476889/ignoring-an-invalid-filter-among-multiple-filters-on-a-dataframe) by the OP [Akshay Sehgal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755954/akshay-sehgal) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>